# Force compile error when obsolete method is used in another obsolete method

Tags: .net, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I am writing some fixture code for fitnesse in DotNet 4.0 and wanted to protect my api methods from being used within the codebase. I thought this could accomplished using the [Obsolete] attribute, however this will not generate a compile error if you use an obsolete method within another method marked obsolete.

```
[Obsolete("Used only externally", true)]
public void Method1() {
}

[Obsolete("Used only externally", true)]
public void Method2() {
    Method1();
}
```

I would like the above code to generate a compile error. Are there any other ways to solve this problem? Perferably within the DotNet framework itself?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be putting your fixture code into the assembly you wish to test. Rather, you should create a separate project for your fixture code. The fixture code should access your 'System under test' using the same public API as other clients of the assembly.

And the tests you write in FitNesse only access the fixture assembly.

```
+----------------+    +-----------------+    +-------------------+
| FitNesse Tests | -> | Fixture Assembly| -> | System under test |
+----------------+    +-----------------+    +-------------------+
                                                   ^
                       +----------------+          |
                       | Other Clients  | ---------+
                       +----------------+
```

Comment: The Fixture code is wrapping Selenium Web driver. If I separate the logic into two separate assemblies I have the same issue, mainly I would like to enforce a rule where methods in a given assembly cannot call each other.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a real example of your use case, but if you want to protect your API methods from being called from other assemblies, why not make use of the `internal` access modifier?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx

Comment: I was trying to abstract out the use case. The reason I want this is that for every method I expose to fitnesse I have to add some boiler plate code.

1) Wrap everything in a try catch.
2) Call the same method before doing any work.
3) Translate the exception so that fitnesse will display it differently.

Calling one of these specials methods from another will break things.

Comment: @JoshuaJewell - I understand now, the real problem is you are adding code directly to a library just for the purposes of testing it. You shouldn't be doing this at all, adding `Obsolete` attributes is just a bandaid to the problem. If you include more detail in your OP maybe people can provide an alternative approach.

Comment: Can you explain why you need special methods to call from FitNesse? Generally FitNesse and your fixture code should call methods that are part of your normal production code.  There may be other ways to accomplish what you need on the FitNesse side.

Comment: My fixture code is using the Selenium web driver and extending its functionality by providing things like screen shot links into the Fitnesse test results.